# (DOORS/DXL) Script for Split Object text in some atributtes using Tab

Tags: ibm-doors

I'm using for for a year but now I have to modify small scripts and I'm a newbie with `DXL`. I have searched in before questions but I don't know how I can do it.

I have to develope a script that analyzes all objects in the same formal module to extract from each "object text" different strings separated by tab, to be written in other different attributes of the same object.

The formal module contents has been imported from Word. In that way that normal text format is defined as "object text" and every Title style is associated to a given level heading. In that way each object is provided with object heading or object text (but not both at the same time). Objects with object heading doesn't require any further action. However for objects provided with object text, I have to extract from object text some atributes separated by tabs.

For example a typical object text could be:

```
NNNN       TEXT/TABLE/OLE OBJECT/ANY OTHER STRING      (XXXXXX)     (YYYYYY)
```

After apply the script it should be converted as:

```
Attribute 1: NNNN
Object Text: TEXT/TABLE/OLE OBJECT/ANY OTHER STRING
Attribute 2: XXXXXX
Attribute 3: YYYYYY
```

I have small script as example but I have passed all the morning trying to modify it to get I need but I can't do it:

```
Object o = current
//bool get_text(Object o) {return o."Object Heading" "" != ""}
string get_text(Object o)
{
    if (o."Object Heading" "" != "")
        return "Object Heading" 
    else 
        return "Object Text"
}
Regexp r_id = regexp "(http://0-9a-z/.+) "
for o in current Module do
{
    string texto = o.(get_text(o))
    if (r_id text)
    {
        o."Attribute 1" = textmatch 1
        string input = richTextWithOle(o.(get_text(o)))
        string output = cutRichText(input, 0, length(textmatch 1))
        o.(get_text(o)) = richText(output) 
    }

}
```

Comment: Please follow the indentation next time.

Comment: @Abhishek Bhatia Thank you for correct my messages. I'm sorry. Please forgive me I'm newbie at this web too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This was a complicated one, but I think I have it figured out. Thanks for posting this because I may find it useful in the future as well.

I tried this out and it seems to work:

```
Object o

string get_text(Object o)
{
    if (o."Object Heading" "" != "")
        return "Object Heading"
    else 
        return "Object Text"
}

char cTab = '\t'  //The tab character to find
Buffer b = create
string tmp = ""   //Needed to concatenate buffer parts
int offset = 0

for o in current Module do
{
    string attr = get_text(o)
    b = o.attr                      //Put the contents in the buffer
    offset = contains(b, cTab)      //Find the first tab
    o."Attribute 1" = b[0:offset-1] //Set the first Attribute
    b = b[offset+1:]                //Remove the first attribute from the text

    offset = contains(b, cTab)
    if(offset > -1)
    {
      if(attr == "Object Heading") o.attr = b[0:offset-1]

      b = b[offset+1:]

      offset = contains(b, cTab)
      if(offset > -1)
      {
        o."Attribute 2" = b[1:offset-2] //Set the second Attribute without the ()
        b = b[offset+1:]

        o."Attribute 3" = b[1:length(b)-2]  //Set the third Attribute without the ()
      } else {
        o."Attribute 2" = b[1:length(b)-2]  //Set the second Attribute without the ()
      }
    } else {
      if(attr == "Object Heading") o.attr = b[0:]
    }

    if(attr == "Object Text")
    {
      b = richTextWithOle(o.attr) ""     //This section removes the attributes from the contents without losing the rich text formatting and OLEs that may be present.

      string word = o."Attribute 1"
      offset = contains(b, word, 0)
      tmp = b[0:offset-1] "" b[(offset+length(word)+5):]
      b = tmp

      word = "(" o."Attribute 2" ")"
      offset = contains(b, word, 0)
      if(offset > -1)
      {
        tmp = b[0:offset-6] "" b[offset+length(word):]
        b = tmp
      }

      word = "(" o."Attribute 3" ")"
      offset = contains(b, word, 0)
      if(offset > -1)
      {
        tmp = b[0:offset-6] "" b[offset+length(word):]
      }

      o.attr = richText(tmp)      //Set the Object Text or Heading
    }
}

delete b                        //Release the buffer resources
```

Let me know if this gives you any trouble or if you want more detailed explination of the code.

EDIT: I updated the above code to take care of the issues you mentioned. It should be all set now. Let me know if you have any more trouble with it.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's very useful for me.

At first it gives me run-time error. In order to try it, I had to modify line for set the object text or heading. I have changed "richtext(tmp)" by "richTextWithOle(tmp)".

I think this script could be so useful for many people. You can maintain hierachy (as rtf import), and some attributes information (as spreadsheet import).

Comment: It works fine but I'm still need to correct 2 things in order I can use it. I hope you can help me with this:
1.- I need that objects wih object text, shall be splitted exactly as you have programmed. However, objects without object text(they are provided only with Object heading) shall be splitted only by Attribute 1 and Object Heading.
2.- All objects with object text have at least 1 tab(attribute 1+Object Text), but other tabs(attribute 2 & 3) could be missing. In that case they should be ignored. Now if any of them is missing a run-time error is shown.
Thank you for your help!!

Comment: Thank you. It works perfect for Object Heading but for Object Text, altough it is well splitted in Object text and their attributtes, the new attributes aren't deleted from original Object Text. I'm sorry for disturb you again. I have tried to modify it but I don't know DXL, and I tried to modify the code sometimes without success.

Comment: Hi, could you check my before comment??

Comment: I just tested it again, and it appears to be working fine. I ran it on 3 text objects and 3 heading objects and they all copy correctly into the attributes then the attribute text is removed from the Heading or Text. I don't know why it isn't working for you, or how I would fix it since as far as I can tell it works as is. Can you post some example objects that are not working?

Comment: Hi! I have found the mistake. I had changed "richtext(tmp)" by "richTextWithOle(tmp)" because I have an object with an object ole inserted. Whether I maintain richtext, the script runs properly but the object with the image stop it. Whether I change richtext by richtextwithole, script runs without errors but do not delete atributes from object text. So I'm going to delete ole object, in order to be inserted after run the script. Thank you!! All is clear now! Your help has been very useful for me.

Comment: No problem, please mark the question as answered. And good luck!